# error in bind_rows in R when integrating multiple csv files into one dataframe

Tags: r, type-conversion, dplyr, readr

I was trying to integrate multiple csv files in a directory into one dataframe using `dplyr::bind_rows` and `readr::read_csv`. I used below R codes.

```
files <- list.files(path = "./mypath/", full.names = TRUE)
df <- files %>%
lapply(read_csv) %>%
bind_rows(.id = "file")
```

It worked fine before actually, but suddenly R returns this error message as below.

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Column `datetime` can't be converted from character to POSIXct/POSIXt
```

How do I pass this error? I tried to convert column type before `bind_rows` but did not succeed.

p.s. I added how the csv files look like

```
datetime        id
01/01/12 1:23   1
07/04/14 12:19  2
```

Comment: What do your csv files look like? Can you share example?

Comment: @Tung I just did. Other than the problematic `datetime` column, they are all considered as characters or integers

Comment: Something is still being left out.  Can you narrow it down to two files (and a subset of rows for each file) and share that?  It looks like at least one file's `datetime` values aren't formatted consistently.  If you're correctly representing the csv and your `readr::read_csv()` call, then it will be a single character columns (with `datetime` and `id` smashed together.  But if that were the case, it wouldn't try to be converting to a POSIXct.

Comment: @Layray: you can copy and paste the content of each csv file to https://pastebin.com/ then add the link to your question. Two files should do it as wibeasley mentioned